# Converting smiles and links of a text in a function

Tags: php, str-replace

i am trying to convert smileys symbols into image and links into anchors in a function
i tried more than 10 times to solve but couldnt, 
i am new in php.

here is my code :

```
 <?php
 $text = "hey :/  Theere is 2 links andc3 smiles in this text  http://google.com   then    trun nto http://yahoo.com";


function cust_text($string)
{
$content_array = explode(" ", $string);
$output = '';

foreach($content_array as $content)
{

// check word starts with http://
if(substr($content, 0, 7) == "http://")
$content = '<a href="' . $content . '">' . $content . '</a>';

//starts word with www.
if(substr($content, 0, 4) == "www.")
$content = '<a href="http://' . $content . '">' . $content . '</a>';

$output .= " " . $content;

}
output = trim($output);

$smiles = array(':/'  => 'E:\smiles\sad.jpg');
foreach($smiles as $key => $img) {

$msg =   str_replace($key, '<img src="'.$img.'" height="18" width="18" />',       $output);}

return $msg;
}

echo cust_text($text); 

?>
```

in result smileys are replacing :/ in http://
pls help
thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You should not link to E:\ . When you put your script online only you can see the smiley. You should make a "relative link" to your smiley:  src="directory/smiley.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:
$smiles = array(':/'  => 'E:\smiles\sad.jpg');

in this:
$smiles = array(' :/ '  => 'E:\smiles\sad.jpg');

Note the space in front of and behind your smiley. Now it won't match the http:/ anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this with regular expressions:

Change this:

```
$msg =   str_replace($key, '<img src="'.$img.'" height="18" width="18" />',       $output);
```

into this:

```
$msg = preg_replace('~'.preg_quote($key).'(?<!http:/)~', '<img src="'.$img.'" height="18" width="18" />', $output);
```

But I must say, for a beginner this is not the easiest solution.

This uses a "negative lookbehind" expression in the regex. This does about the same as the string replace, with the difference that it looks back to see if :/ wasn't part of http:/
The two ~ characters are the starter and finisher for the regex. If you want to make a smiley that contains a ~ you need to escape it like so: \~

You can fix this with a str_replace:

```
$key =   str_replace('~', '\~', $key);
```